# How do I integrate Azure devops board and Github?

Tags: github, azure-devops, integration, azure-boards

I have been made the project administrator for a project in Azure Devops. Also I have the code in git repo and looking to integrate Git and Devops board see all the code updates in Azure.

And I'm trying to do that following the below link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/github/connect-to-github?view=azure-devops

While doing that I don't see the below message that I need access as Project Administrator, however my name is listed under Project admin. How can I resolve this

[image]

Comment: Validate this: You must be a member of the Project Administrators group **and** the project's Contributors group.

Comment: I added myself in the Project Contributors group and it works fine now. Thanks for the help, much appreciated !